# Have to make synchronous calls from Button onClick in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

I have button which is making two calls in onClick, a function `resetFilterItems` which resets the filter in my state and simultaneously my `getNetworkViewData` is also api is also called.

I am not able to reset my filters firsts so making a call with incorrect payload. How can I first reset the filters `props.filterStatus`, `props.filterCapabilities` and then make a call synchronously in this situation?

```
               <Button
                type="secondary"
                onClick={() => {
                  props.resetFilterItems(
                    props.filterStatus,
                    props.filterCapabilities
                  );
                  props.getNetworkViewData(
                    getSearchQueryParam(),
                    props.partnerId
                  );
                }}
                size="medium"
              >
                Clear all
              </Button>
```

Comment: depends .... what does `props.resetFilterItems` function return?

Comment: Hey @JaromandaX, it returns nothing, just sets the props.filterStatus and props.filterCapabilities to empty array.

Comment: and you say it's asynchronous?

Comment: Yes correct it's asynchronous right now

Comment: what makes it asynchronous? did you write it? what sort of asynchronous function doesn't allow you to get the results in a callback?

Comment: As my 2nd calls(api) doesn't wait for the first to get complete and update the state and in the meantime the second api calls starts, hence making a async call.

Comment: no, that's the result of it being asynchronous, I do understand what asynchronous means - but thanks for the "lesson", champ

Answer (score 1):

Try to call your another method in the `resetFilterItems` in this method.

So that way your state will clear and you can call another method after that.

Or share those 2 methods to get an idea more about your code flow.

You can use `useEffect` with your state dependencies. And call your Api in `useEffect` whenever you change your state.

```
useEffect(()=>{
                 props.getNetworkViewData(
                    getSearchQueryParam(),
                    props.partnerId
                  );
},[props.filterStatus])
```

Or you want to reset your states after API call then reset them in API response method.

Comment: Here is the reducer call for resetFilterItems:
`
case resetFilterItems:
      return {
        ...state,
        filterStatus: Object.assign([]),
        filterCapabilities: Object.assign([]),
      };
`

And the other one is a get API call.

Comment: Please paste them in  your question.